# Find Codeception elements with more than one CSS class

Tags: css-selectors, functional-testing, acceptance-testing, codeception

i have something like the following markup:

```
<body>
  <div class="navigation">...</div>
  <div class="messages error">...</div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
</body>
```

Now I have some codeception tests (with PHPBrowser Module), to check, if the "div" with messages is not existing. This doesn't work for container with more than one class. They don't seem to be match with this:

```
$I->dontSeeElement('.messages');
$I->dontSeeElement('.error');
$I->dontSeeElement('.messages .error');
$I->dontSeeElement('div.messages.error');
```

How can I match this container?

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: That's really odd. Are you still able to match `.navigation` and `.content` while being unable to match `.messages.error`? If so, I'd chalk this one up to a bug.

Comment: `".navigation"` and `".content"` is no problem. `".messages.error"` is also a combination I tried before and does not match with the markup.

Comment: every figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize your xpaths to below:

```
$I->dontSeeElement(['xpath'=>'//div[contains(@class,'messages')]']);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for now, but did not solve the CSS selector "bug".